# Использование переменных объявленных в for

Tags: c, циклы

Почему недопустим такой вариант?

```
int sum=0;
for(int j=0; j<n; j++);
 {
   sum+=mas[0][j];
   sum+=mas[n-1][j];
 }
```

А такой компилируется:

```
int sum=0;
int j=0;
for( ; j<n; j++);
{
 sum+=mas[0][j];
 sum+=mas[n-1][j];
}
```

(mas уже инициализирован)

Comment: В подобных вопросах стоит указывать какое именно сообщение об ошибке Вы видите (его текст), а также какой компилятор используете (например, gcc version xxx) и с какими ключами его вызываете.  А в Вашем случае, скажем `gcc` с ключем `-std=gnu99` скомпилит оба варианта (конечно, если лишнюю `;` убрать), а без него только второй. Ключи компилятора можно посмотреть в [man gcc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я думаю, оба варианта компилируются, только первый выдаёт предупреждение из-за того, что этот код содержит undefined behaviour.

Переменную `sum` инициализировать за вас компилятор не будет. А использование неинициализировнной переменной есть даже не unspecified, а undefined behaviour. Это значит, что не только «начальное значение переменной может быть любым», но «при выполнении программы может произойти всё, что угодно, включая форматирование жёсткого диска».

---

Окей, вопрос отредактирован, теперь обе переменные инициализированы, ищем дальше.

Но я не заметил ещё одну ошибку. У вас написано `for(int j=0; j<n; j++);`, точка с запятой в конце лишняя.

В результате в первом случае переменная `j` локальна в блоке
и не видна за его пределами: этот код можно равносильно записать так:

```
for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
    ;

{
    sum+=mas[0][j];
    sum+=mas[n-1][j];
}
```

Comment: Нет. В 1ом случае - IntelliSense: идентификатор "j" не определен

Comment: Упс. В самом деле, точка с запятой. Без нее работает. Спасибо.

Comment: @Olfy: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 5):

Насколько мне известно, в Си в принципе нельзя объявлять переменные внутри `for`. (внутри круглых скобочек).
*Как меня поправили в комментариях, это до стандарта С99. Стандарты С99 и выше ведут себя в данном случае, как в С++*

```
int sum;
int j;
for(j=0; j<n; j++){
    sum+=mas[0][j];
    sum+=mas[n-1][j];
}
```

В языке С++ такая конструкция допустима, но эти переменные видны только внутри этого цикла. В примере автора блок цикла заканчивается точкой с запятой, из-за чего в следующем блоке компилятор ничего не знает о `j`.

```
//Скомпилируется
int sum;
for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
    sum+=mas[0][j];
    sum+=mas[n-1][j];
}

//Не скомпилируется
int sum;
for(int j=0; j<n; j++); //Область видимости j ограничена этой строкой
{
    sum+=mas[0][j];
    sum+=mas[n-1][j];
}
```

Comment: Возможно) Но это все равно означает, что в Си на это влияет стандарт и может быть ситуация, когда не объявишь, в отличии от С++.